# django post api through postman

Tags: django, django-rest-viewsets

**Hi when I try to hit the post api from postman I am receiving the response from API but the request is not received from postman
when I print the request it showing  but not the data
and i attached the screenshot of postman
**
[image]

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
# Create your views here.

@csrf_exempt
def email(request):
  print(request)
  subject = request.POST.get('subject', 'hello')
  body = request.POST.get('body', 'very bad')
  senderEmail = request.POST.get('senderEmail', 'my_email@gmail.com') 
  send_mail(subject, body, 'sender@gmail.com', [senderEmail], fail_silently=False)
  return HttpResponse("Email Send.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the context of your project is, but you can use serializers and write something like: `return Response(serializer.initial_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)`. The `serializer.initial_data` would be the data you are initially sending, and it would show up in your Postman response box. Hope this helps. (You can read more about serializers for Django [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)).

Comment: Can you share your `urls.py`? Also, you should add `@api_view['POST']` at the top of your function name so it can receive POST requests.

Comment: This my urls.py
`
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('send/', include('mail.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
`

mail.urls
`
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.email, name="email"),
]
`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of raw data , choose a form data in a postman.
[image]

In a python code you can change your code like below:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def email(request):
    formDataReceved = request.POST
    subjectReceived = formDataReceved['subject'].strip()
    bodyReceived = formDataReceved['body'].strip()
    senderEmailReceived = formDataReceved['senderEmail'].strip()
    send_mail(subjectReceived, bodyReceived, 'sender@gmail.com', [senderEmailReceived], fail_silently=False)
    return HttpResponse("Email Send.")
```